# Gson throws IllegalStateException when attempting to parse List

Tags: java, json, list, gson

I am learning data persistence and this is my first attempt at JSON.  I have read a few guides and from what little I can tell the code has been correct in both attempts at storing the objects.  I get the file written using Gson but Gson throws exceptions when attempted to parse the objects using the fromJson() method.  My question is as follows:

- If I am using the same type to convert to/from JSON what am I missing that would tell Gson how to properly parse my object(s)?

I have tried three different approaches, two of which are included below.  First I tried storing the wrapper class for the list of objects which a guide suggested I should be able to do:

```
public class JSONConverter {
    private static Path path = Paths.get("src\\json\\JSONList.json");
    private static Type stockType = new TypeToken<StocksList>(){}.getType();

    public static void convertToJSON(StocksList stocks, Path path) {
        Gson json = new Gson();     
        String storedStocks = json.toJson(stocks, stockType);// I also tried "StocksList.class" here            
        checkForFile(path);
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            writer.write(storedStocks);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //handle later
        }
    }

    static void checkForFile(Path path) {
        if (Files.notExists(path)) {
            try {
                Files.createFile(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //handle later
            }
        }
    }

    public static StocksList convertFromJSON(Path path) {
        StocksList stocksList = new StocksList();
        Gson json = new Gson();
        String fromJson;
        try {
            fromJson = Files.readAllBytes(path).toString();
            stocksList = json.fromJson(fromJson, stockType);
            return stocksList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return stocksList;
        }
    }
}
```

My second approach was to get the list out of the wrapper class and try to convert that to JSON:

```
public class JSONConverter {
    private static Path path = Paths.get("src\\json\\JSONList.json");
    private static Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Stock>>(){}.getType();

    public static void convertToJSON(StocksList stocks, Path path) {
        Gson json = new Gson();     
        List<Stock> temp = stocks.getStocks();
        String storedStocks = json.toJson(temp, listType);
        checkForFile(path);
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            writer.write(storedStocks);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //handle later
        }
    }

    static void checkForFile(Path path) {
        if (Files.notExists(path)) {
            try {
                Files.createFile(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //handle later
            }
        }
    }


    public static StocksList convertFromJSON(Path path) {
        StocksList stocksList = new StocksList();
        List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<>();
        Gson json = new Gson();
        String fromJson;
        try {
            fromJson = Files.readAllBytes(path).toString();
            stocks = json.fromJson(fromJson, listType);
            //wraps the list in the stockslist class
            stocksList.setStocks(stocks);
            return stocksList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return stocksList;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the JSON written by the first method using the second approach.  The first looks like it except adds "{ "stocks" :" (what you see below) "}":

```
[
{
    "ticker": "INTC",
    "currentPrice": "45.94",
    "marginOfSafety": 0.25,
    "lastDate": "2019-12-28",
    "cashYield": "7.4",
    "MCap": "196485365760",
    "enterpriseValue": "281213850000",
    "sharesOut": "4417000000",
    "oddPercentGrowth": false,
    "newCompany": false,
    "safeValue": "51.35",
    "fairValue": "68.47",
    "evEbitda": "8.56",
    "fcf": [
        "16932000000",
        "14611750000"
    ],
    "rOnAssets": "21",
    "rOnCapital": "20",
    "croic": "16.47",
    "equityToDebt": "3.0",
    "cashOnHand": "4194000000",
    "cashToDebt": "0.17",
    "changeInDebt": "210000000",
    "capEfficiency": [
        "18",
        "7",
        "-26",
        "-21",
        "1"
    ],
    "fcfChange": [
        "18.81",
        "11.71"
    ],
    "profitMargin": [
        "46",
        "38"
    ]
},
{
    "ticker": "HCC",
    "currentPrice": "12.99",
    "marginOfSafety": 0.5,
    "lastDate": "2018-12-31",
    "cashYield": "46.1",
    "MCap": "664587904",
    "enterpriseValue": "1572623480",
    "sharesOut": "52812000",
    "oddPercentGrowth": true,
    "newCompany": true,
    "safeValue": "236.94",
    "fairValue": "473.87",
    "evEbitda": "2.59",
    "fcf": [
        "457776000",
        "306126750"
    ],
    "rOnAssets": "49",
    "rOnCapital": "59",
    "croic": "38.77",
    "equityToDebt": "1.0",
    "cashOnHand": "205577000",
    "cashToDebt": "0.44",
    "changeInDebt": "125283000",
    "capEfficiency": [
        "292",
        "798",
        "-365",
        "-397",
        "-1"
    ],
    "fcfChange": [
        "33.9",
        "33.9"
    ],
    "profitMargin": [
        "40",
        "8"
    ]
}
]
```

Both throw:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 12

(this line changes to "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2" when using the first approach).
    at

> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
>   ...

I was going to try adding each object individually to a JSONArray but when I started encountering trouble there I thought I should just ask.  The guide mentioned that reflection was important and I am guessing that my trouble lies therein due to the second line of the stack trace but again, this is my first time trying to use JSON.  If I forgot to include anything let me know and I'll post it in a comment.

Thanks for the help.

ADDENDUM: the objects only throw these exceptions when being written to and pulled from a file.  They do not throw when being converted to a JSON String and then back again.  It occurs whether I use Files.write() or Files.newBufferedWriter().

Comment: Your JSON is array should be end with ]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the discrepancy.  I'll edit that in the question.  I copied only the first portion of the array to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who viewed my question.  I reached out to Gson's github page and they responded with the following corrections to my class:

> All the code you've provided can be greatly fixed, improved and refactored.
>
> No need to create multiple Gson instances: they are relatively
>   expensive to instantiate, but are designed to be thread-safe and
>   immutable therefore can be reused. No need to serialize to and
>   deserialize from java.lang.String -- this is just expensive as long as
>   it has to create multiple strings in the heap merely wasting the heap
>   and time decreasing the performance. Why it does not work in your case
>   is that Files.readAllBytes(...) returns byte[] you're trying to
>   convert to a string. In Java, no arrays have an intuitive toString
>   implementation (you can check it by simply printing any byte array to
>   System.out). In order to convert it to a string (that might be a
>   memory-consuming instance), new String(byte[]) (or even new
>   String(byte[], Charset)) is an appropriate way. I don't really
>   remember how Files works, but there's probably no need to check the
>   file to exist: they can be overwritten without any additional checks.
>   No type tokens are necessary in this case: StockList.class is a Type
>   too. Essentially, all is you need is just as follows:

```
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .disableHtmlEscaping()
    .disableInnerClassSerialization()
    .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final StocksList before = new StocksList(ImmutableList.of(new Stock("INTC"), new 
 Stock("HCC")));
    final Path path = Paths.get("doc.json");
    write(path, before);
    final StocksList after = read(path);
    System.out.println(after.equals(before));
}

private static void write(final Path path, final StocksList stocks)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new 
FileOutputStream(path.toFile())) ) {
        gson.toJson(stocks, writer);
     }
}

 private static StocksList read(final Path path)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new 
 FileInputStream(path.toFile())) ) {
         return gson.fromJson(reader, StocksList.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks to lyubomyr-shaydariv (Gson contributor) for the answer.

Comment: If submitting an answer given me by an outside party is inappropriate I apologize.